# Convert char for bit data to integer in DB2

Tags: sql, db2, bit-manipulation

I'm writing a DB2 user-defined function for which I need an array of non-negative integers, which I represent as a **varchar for bit data**. I plan to use two bytes for each integer (giving me a maximum value of 2^16-1, which is acceptable).

I can convert an integer to a char for bit data by using the **chr** function, but how do I get it back to an integer?

Any additional advice on bit manipulation in DB2 procedures would be helpful as well, as I can't seem to find much documentation on it. I'm using v9.1 on Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if CHR is actually what you want.  According to [the documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/r0000778.htm), the CHR function:

> Returns the character that has the ASCII code value specified by the argument.  The argument can be either INTEGER or SMALLINT. The value of the argument should be between 0 and 255; otherwise, the return value is null.

The opposite of the CHR function is the [ASCII function.](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/r0000770.htm)

Full list of DB2 scalar procedures is [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/c0000767.htm).

I'm not sure if writing a UDF in this way is the best for what you're trying to do.  You may want to consider writing a stored procedure that's not in SQL.  There's a list of supported languages, like Java, C, C++ etc.

Comment: ASCII is exactly the function I needed. Thanks!